# Having trouble understanding how to resize a dynamic array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I need to read in a list of ints and store them in an Array. The amount of ints is unknown and thus the array needs to be resized if it becomes full and there is more integers to read in. They'll only be read in once and the program will know the user is done entering when they enter a certain value to terminate the loop.

Anyway I realize I'll be using malloc() and realloc() but am slightly confused. We are to use scanf() to read in the values.

Say I initially create the array to be of SIZE 10. I imagine I'd use if/else statements within the loop to determine when to use realloc but I'm not sure how to check for that.

```
int value;
int index;
int* myArray;

// Allocate space for array of 10 ints to start
myArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
index = 0;

// Prompt
printf("Please enter as many integers as you would like.\n");
printf("Enter the integer '123' to indicate when you are finished.\n\n");
scanf("%d", &value);
while (value != 123) {

    scanf("%d", &value);
    myArray[index] = value;
    index++;

}
```

I think this reads in the integers right and stores them in myArray. Now when it reaches the 10th int I'll want to double the array size and so forth everytime it reaches the limit right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you're ignoring the first integer. The loop body should write to the array before waiting for the next integer, like so:

```
scanf("%d", &value);
while (value != 123) {
    myArray[index] = value;
    index++;    
    scanf("%d", &value);

}
```

Now, you will need to keep a variable to hold the size of the current array. Then, before writing to the array, if the index is equal to the size of the current array, you need to realloc:

```
arr_sz = SIZE;
scanf("%d", &value);
while (value != 123) {
    if (index == arr_sz) {
        arr_sz *= 2;
        myArray = realloc(myArray, sizeof(*myArray)*arr_sz);
    }
    myArray[index] = value;
    index++;    
    scanf("%d", &value);
}
```

You might want to test and make sure that `malloc()` and `realloc()` do not return `NULL`.

On a final side-note, I would suggest you to change the first allocation from:

```
myArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
```

to the slightly more maintainable form:

```
myArray = malloc(sizeof(*myArray)*SIZE);
```

That way, even if the type of `myArray` changes, you don't need to update this line of code.

Comment: the first malloc() call can be eliminated by: int *myArray = NULL;  SIZE = 1; because realloc() will work correctly when the contents of the myArray pointer is NULL.

Comment: perhaps I'm wrong, but the realloc() second parameter needs to be (sizeof(*myArray)*arr_sz)  as the new allocation is how many (in this case) int sized item to be allocated, not how many entries (bytes) to be allocated  I agree, ALWAYS check the returned value from malloc and realloc to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @user3629249 Yep, true. I didn't mention it because I don't want to confuse the OP: we would have to be careful, because we can't simply initialize `arr_sz` to 0 because of the multiplication. Maybe turn `arr_sz *= 2` into `arr_sz = (arr_sz+1)*2`. And you're right about `sizeof` - good catch. I updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer and comments guys. Got it going now, thanks!